# Converting from OOK to ASK at 433MHz

Tags: rf, modulation

I need to convert messages sent from a device using OOK modulation to ASK so it can communicate with another device that modulates in ASK.

I can't modify either of those devices. I was wondering if it's possible to begin with. I've seen modules that claim they can work in both ASK and OOK but none of them explain how to use them; all of the examples omit this sort of configuration.

Comment: Do you know if the protocols used by the devices are the same apart from the modulation? OOK is just a special case of ASK, so if the devices can understand each others data, it may "just work".

Comment: The first is a "hub" that can control RF devices by listening and learning the commands and then broadcast them as needed. But when I try to learn one command it can not be listened by the hub. So a "protocol" is not needed since it can learn what value to transmit. Supposedly both the hub and the RF device use 433mhz band, but the hub works as OOK and the RF devicee (an alarm system) as ASK.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. Maybe you can get some ideas from this video on how to solve your problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0fSEbGEY-Q

Comment: @MarcoZollinger Thanks. I'll check it out! To the one who downvoted please note I don't know anything about this so I don't know how can I improve the question. It's not even homework, I'm just a simple user trying to understand and make two of my purchased devices work together.

Comment: @Areks, I wasn't the downvoter, but it was probably because you used mhz instead of MHz. It might seem pedantic to you, but they have a different technical meaning so it's a big deal to us. It would be like a programmer calling a list an array and expecting people to know what he meant (insert better example here). I modified the title to correct it.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Annie! I have no problem with people downvoting, but if they don't give me feedback I can't do better next time.

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense.  Format conversion would be tantamount to building your own learning hub anyway, so why not just do that?   Or contact the maker of the existing learning hub and ask them to figure out why it isn't capturing the signal.   Do you have any independent evidence, say from an RTL-SDR dongle, that the signal is on the frequency you think?  The practical form of this question is off topic as the usage of a consumer product, and the engineering form lacks too many details and is too broad to be concisely answerable within the format of SE.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 1. because the hub is controllable from the internet and I can't build my own due to lack of skills. 2. I wasn't aware than what I want was that complex. 3. I already contacted the maker and they said they might support ASK eventually but sounded like "not really". 4. No, but the product label said it was ASK433M, so I assumed it meant 433MHZ ASK modulated. 5. Yes I know I'm ignorant about this topic. That's why my question is lacking in quality, but I don't know how to ask it better. This might be the reason why my google searching has been in vain.

Comment: @Areks You should include some context in your question (not the comments): which devices you're talking about, which signals you want to convert, etc. Oscilloscope plots would be nice to see.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, assuming you have a device that supports both modulation formats (example for such devices are the CC1xxx devices from TI). You will have to receive the packet in one format, change the device modulation format, and transmit it.

Comment: Is there any way to research about it? I've read a ton about modulation but no one gives practical examples : / I was trying to  "build" (preferable with arduino) a third device as a middleman but I don't have a starting point.

Comment: Sure, it's possible - but it would probably easier to just build one's own learning hub.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Radiohead library,available on github. Then get an OOK receiver and an ASK transmitter.
Receive a batch of bytes, send them out.

https://www.google.com/search?ei=xRiQW6qAF4O-zwKjmogw&q=433+mhz+ook+modulation+receiver&oq=433+mhz+ook+modulation+receiver&gs_l=psy-ab.3...32230.35596..36172...0.0..0.176.1254.0j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.CqRGeZpOuHY

https://www.google.com/search?ei=6hiQW4KuI9LszgLXgKgQ&q=433+mhz+ask+modulation+transmiter&oq=433+mhz+ask+modulation+transmiter&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.23557.31618..31944...0.0..0.196.4295.0j26......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i13i30j33i21j33i13i21.usPjLVBt9U4

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon, as once they go dead, the answer becomes useless.

Comment: If they do, it's just a google search to find again.